# Trucanted string in subprocess.call()

Tags: python, windows

```
import os,subprocess,io

path = "C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\unconverted"
des = "C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\converted"

    def convert( path, des):
        command = "ffmpeg -i " +path+" -ab 192k "+des + "-y "
        subprocess.call(command)

    for song in os.listdir(path):
        filepath = os.path.join(path,song)
        despath = os.path.join(des, song[len(song)-3]+"mp3")
        convert(filepath,despath)
    print("complete")
```

this code return this error

```
C:\Users\Awesome\Music\unconverted\KYLE: No such file or directory
```

the full file name is `C:\Users\Awesome\Music\unconverted\KYLE - Playinwitme (feat Kehlani).m4a` I have no idea why it is truncating after the first word.

Comment: One quick solution that I can think of is to surround the path also in the command with double quotes.  "ffmpeg -i \"" +path+"\" -ab 192k "+des + "-y

Comment: jus tried it, didn't work

Comment: A few notes: It's best to split imports into multiple lines. pathlib is a better alternative to os.path.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of forming a command string and passing it to subprocess.call, passing it as a list of arguments to the method will do the trick.

```
import os,subprocess,io

path = "C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\unconverted"
des = "C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\converted"

def convert( path, des):
    command_lis = ["ffmpeg", "-i", path, "-ab", "192k",des,"-y"]
    subprocess.call(command_lis)

for song in os.listdir(path):
    filepath = os.path.join(path,song)
    despath = os.path.join(des, song[0:len(song)-3]+"mp3")
    convert(filepath,despath)
print("complete")
```

Comment: It looks like the OP wants to replace the extension with ".mp3" and forgot to use a slice, but it would be better to use `splitext`. For example, `os.path.splitext(song)[0] + ".mp3"`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the command will have a path with a space in it like this `ffmpeg -i C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\unconverted\\KYLE - Playinwitme (feat Kehlani).m4a .....`,
You should remove the spaces from the name of the file or insert the whole name inside double-quotes. Also change `song[len(song)-3]+"mp3"` to `song[0 : len(song)-3]+"mp3"`

```
import os,subprocess,io

path = "C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\unconverted"
des = "C:\\Users\\Awesome\\Music\\converted"

    def convert( path, des):
        command = "ffmpeg -i " + f"\"{path}\"" + " -ab 192k " + f"\"{des}\"" + " -y"
        subprocess.call(command)

    for song in os.listdir(path):
        filepath = os.path.join(path,song)
        despath = os.path.join(des, song[0 : len(song)-3]+"mp3")
        convert(filepath,despath)

    print("complete")
```